# Recursive CTE Query - I want to return @Id as Part of resultSet

Tags: sql

```
DECLARE @Id INT
SELECT @Id = 71495
;WITH cte_parents (ParentId)
AS
(    SELECT ParentId  From dbo.TableOne WHERE ChildId =@Id  
UNION ALL
SELECT cp.parentId FROM dbo.TableOne cp
INNER JOIN  cte_parents 
ON cp.ChildId=cte_parents.ParentId  -- Recursive member (RM) is referencing cte_name.
 )

SELECT * FROM cte_parents 


 This Query finds out all the parents for a given value. I have a table with two columns 

 TableOne

 ParentId ChildId
```

The Issue is i want to return @Id as Part of resultSet. In Other words it should return the @Id even if there is  no parent. If there is one parent then it should return two values. One is passing parameter i-e @Id and other one is parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could do this:

```
WITH cte_parents (ParentId) AS
      (SELECT ParentId  From dbo.TableOne WHERE ChildId =@Id  
       UNION ALL
       SELECT cp.parentId
       FROM dbo.TableOne cp INNER JOIN 
            cte_parents 
            ON cp.ChildId=cte_parents.ParentId  -- Recursive member (RM) is referencing cte_name.
      )
SELECT *
FROM cte_parents 
union all
SELECT @id;
```

This just adds the additional row in the final `select` clause.